# Real noise modeling/ noise map generation (image processing, deep learning)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, research-design

I am working on a project with really noisy images. I have trained a detector that can detect the characters but fails in some cases (noise is high).

So far I have gone through many denoising, deblurring, super-resolution papers. The problem with denoising papers is that in almost all of them, they use a specified Gaussian noise to first add noise and trains the model on that. I have tried it but it doesn't work very well in my domain as the source of the noise in my images is different.

**Let's say I have few thousand images (real-data with noise), is there any deep learning/image processing approach which helps me to get a noise map which I'll use to augment my clean images so that I can train denoising models.**

Comment: Do you access to noisy and denoised version of the same image?

Comment: I have only access to noisy images, or you can say I have two set of images, one which are really distorted and noisy, another one with less noise but for different set of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have $m$ noisy images $I_N^{i};i \in [1...m ]$. One way of accomplishing your end goal is as follows:

1. Run single-image learning-based denoising techniques on your noisy images to obtain corresponding clean images. You can use [Deep Image Prior](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10925) ([code](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior)) or [Noise2Void - Learning Denoising from Single Noisy Images](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10980) ([code](https://github.com/juglab/n2v)). These methods learn the image intensity statistics for an image to denoise them as opposed to using a source-pair fixed distribution (e.g. Gaussian). Your model $M(\cdot)$ takes noisy images $I_N^{i}$, and produces corresponding clean images $I_C^{i}$.
2. Using the clean-noisy pairs following step 1 above, train a fully supervised model $P(\cdot)$ to produce noisy image, given a clean image as input. To do this, you can use a strong single-image superresolution architecture ([several options here](https://github.com/YapengTian/Single-Image-Super-Resolution)). Why superresolution? Because noise map has high frequencies, similar to the mask *composited* by superresolution architectures on top of the input image. These masks essentially enhance edges, which has a high frequency structure.
3. Using $P(\cdot)$, forward pass other clean images to create a new dataset for training your original denoising model, this is what you wanted to accomplish.

Noise map would simply be $N^{i}=I_{N}^{i}-I_{C}^{i} $. For training $P(\cdot)$ in step 2, you can apply mild data augmentation, e.g. rotation, scaling (zooming in/out), translation, mild brightness and contrast adjustments.

Comment: thanks so far, I will have to run some experiments to verify your thought process, I will let you know.

Comment: Please let me know if you have additional questions. I would appreciate if you can award me this bounty at the end if you think my answer was reasonable, I need it to ask a bounty question of my own.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, even though I haven't tested it yet but as there were not any better answer and your answer seems reasonable.